# Why isnt the google search function working by pressing "Enter" or "Return" in keyboard?

Tags: html

I am attempting at creating a homepage in which I can set as my browser home page.
Below is a "google search" function that will open google with whatever you searched only if you click the Google button. When I press "enter" in the text area, it reloads my page.

My **problem** is that whenever I press "enter" on the keyboard, it just reloads the page instead of opening google with whatever words I put into the box.

I want google to open with whatever my search box says by pressing enter or the Google button.

```
<form>
    <input class="form-control radius-input" id="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Search on Google..." onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) { location='http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);}" />
    <a class="btn btn-common btn-lg pull-right " id="googleLink" href="notrequired" onclick="this.href='http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);">
        <span>Google</span>
    </a>
</form>
```

If you need more specific context, please let me know and I will provide it to my fullest extent.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why would you use JavaScript? Just make it `<form action="http://www.google.com/search">` and add `name="q"` to the input field.

Answer (score -1):

All I had to do was remove the form tag.

Works as follows:

```
    <input class="form-control radius-input" id="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Search on Google..." onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) { location='http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);}" />
<a class="btn btn-common btn-lg pull-right " id="googleLink" href="notrequired" onclick="this.href='http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);">
    <span>Google</span>
</a>
```